# How to rotate in red black tree

Tags: algorithm, tree, rotation, red-black-tree

I'm trying to solve this exercise with red black tree: I need to insert 2, 1, 4, 5, 9 in this order. After the last input I need to balance it with the **Insert-Fixup** algorithm:
[image]

The part of the algorithm I need to follow is:

```
if z == z.p.right
   z = z.p
   LEFT-ROTATE (T, z)
z.p.color = BLACK
z.p.p.color = RED
RIGHT-ROTATE (T, z.p.p)
```

(Z is the node I want to insert) and z.p is its father. So I tried to follow the steps until the left rotation and this is the result: is it right?
[image]

I searched on internet and I read that there are double rotation algorithm, but I cannot figure out if I can use them here instead of using the single rotation (for example I don't know hot to right rotate the node with the 4).

Comment: You can't rotate right at 4, because it has no left child.  The fixup case you are looking at is not the right one for your tree shape.  It would work if you were inserting into 4's _left_ subtree

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are following the wrong case. I have explained the answer in the following steps. In the last step, i.e. inserting 9, we have to do left-rotate(4) and recoloring.

Following is the pic in which I have explained the steps:

[image]